# How do you avoid mouse use entirely?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, vim, keyboard

Avoiding the use of the mouse entirely is hard today, as most OSes, browsers and software in general are very GUI-oriented. What system, software and general tricks are you using to completely avoid the use of the mouse today?

Comment: @downvoter, mind explaining?

Comment: If you'd like to get rid of the mouse, you should probably use a terminal and the command line. Or a keyboard mouse (an accessibility feature). There's also no realistic way to answer this question without knowing what your requirements are—at the moment you're asking how to drive your car without a steering wheel.

Comment: @slhck here we go again, you guys don't learn. This is a perfectly answerable question and could attract some good tips and advice from someone who is interested on the matter and is probably waiting for a chance to share his experiences. It hasn't been asked for long and is relevant. Just give it time.

Comment: I thought this was a pretty reasonable question, if oddly phrased.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not reasonably answerable at all. If you don't want to use the mouse in a GUI environment that was *built* for users with a mouse, then you should switch to a text-based environment. If there is a physical reason why you can't use a mouse, most OSes have a keyboard mouse feature that allows you to steer the cursor via the numpad. Your question is not even specific to one operating system, and asking for "what others are doing" is not constructive per our [FAQ#dontask]. If you can tell us what specifically you need, I'm happy to reopen the question.

Comment: @SeanD I rephrased it.

Comment: Your last edit made the question even broader and more subjective. Is your real issue that you have to work with OS X and the windows clutter up? Do you want to rearrange the OS X windows via keyboard and navigate through them? That'd be a valid (and interesting) question to ask.

Comment: @slhck you have no idea what you are talking about. It's not specific to an operating system because I'm asking what operating system and software combinations best fit this idea, and this question already has a pretty good answer.

Comment: @slhck do you understand the concept that maybe I do not know a creative solution that someone has developed and if I just kept asking for random specifics such as "how to rearrange OSX windows via keyboard", I could end up with an entirely workflow based on ideas that were solved best by someone? Do you understand the concept of sharing experiences? Have you ever browsed the top questions and analyzed what kind of questions gave space to the best answers SO had? Well, I did. Do it. Your analyze of the situation is horrible, with all due respect.

Comment: If you can point me to a question that is asking for "What do you use?", please do so, and we'll close it accordingly. Again, this question is too broad. Everybody will have a valid answer when they throw in their set of tools. If you want to discuss this question and ask for guidance on how to have it reopened, please do so on [meta]. Thanks. (I should add that your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/537966/how-is-osx-supposed-to-work-without-a-mouse), which was much more specific, was closed for the same reasons.)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files
http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website
http://superuser.com/questions/432844/how-do-i-securely-store-and-manage-180-passwords
http://superuser.com/questions/318653/what-are-some-options-for-transfering-large-files-without-using-the-internet
oh but this is the best
http://superuser.com/questions/31345/what-is-the-best-directory-diff-tool 47k views. How many people helped all around the world? How much work and advancement done? So good you arrived late!

Comment: http://o7.no/1122evL and what a surprise, it's the second result on Google! So whenever someone googles for directory diff, it'll get it's answer on the question you closed. So it's actually the way the programming community, as a whole, solves this specific problem today. Indeed, so good you arrived late, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with what you are saying Dokkat, but there is no point arguing about it on your question. Best to take this conversation to the chat, and talk directly about it to @slhck.

Comment: I didn't see the replies (you need to @-ping users), but those questions – also the directory diff one – are a prime example of the kind of question we don't encourage anymore. The Google result right below, Wikipedia's comparison of diff tools, is what already does a better job than a polling contest in a Q&A site. For further discussion I'd rather point you to [meta] because there, others can weigh in.

Comment: Here are some tools for MacOS and not only to get rid of the mouse
https://superuser.com/questions/537966/how-is-osx-supposed-to-work-without-a-mouse#comment2879305_537966

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well on OSX I use [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/), and on Linux I use [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/) which are both quite apt at turning your window-soup into window-bento. Also a lot of OSX system nonsense can actually be dealt with via AppleScript, in case you don't like clicking away notifications and the like.